# I want to use PHP variable in jQuery in loop

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use PHP variable in jQuery.
I am having a 50 students data in table which having textbox and radio button.
By default textbox is hidden but when I clicked on radio button textbox show in table.

```
$("input[type='radio']").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "2")
        var id = '<?php echo json_encode($absent); ?>';
        //$("input[type='text']").show();
    else
        $("input[type='text']").hide();
});
```

PHP code:

```
        <input name="nxtmark<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" type="text" id="nxtmark<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onblur="onleave(this.name);" maxlength="2" placeholder="Enter Mark" hidden="" />
        <div class="noerrordiv" id="dnxtmark<?php  echo $row[0]; ?>">Mark must not be blank</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="justify">
            <input type="radio" id="rdopresent" name="rdopresent<?php  echo $row['id']; ?>" checked="checked" value="1" />Present
            <input type="radio" id="rdoabsent" name="rdopresent<?php  echo $row['id']; ?>" value="2" />Absent<br />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you're throwing away that `var id=...` because you assign it and then do absolutely nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can show / hide text box without using PHP variable. See below code -

```
$("input[type='radio']").on('change',function() {
  //find input text from the previous 'td' for which name starts with 'nxtmark'
  var $textBox = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input[name^=nxtmark]');

  //show hide text box as per radio button value
  if($(this).val() == "2")
    $textBox.show();
  else
    $textBox.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Problem is just to use PHP variable in jquery then following examples will help you.

if you have to user a php array in jquery then use `json_encode` in PHP not in SCRIPT.

```
<?php 
    $a = array(1,2,3,4); 
    $a = json_encode($a);
    $b = "hello";
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("<?php echo $a;  ?>"); 
    alert("<?php echo $b;  ?>"); 
});
</script>
```